# include works with if but not else

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I doing a Ruby botcamp. I'm supposed to write code that replaces all user input of 's' with 'th' so it reads like Daffy Duck is speaking. If I enter an s it will be replaced with th. That works! But If I don't enter an 's' it's supposed to print that none were included in my elsif statemnt. Instead I'm getting the error 'undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass'. Other than that error, the interpretor is telling me the code is good.

```
print "Input a string: "
user_input=gets.chomp.downcase!
if user_input.include?"s"
user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
puts "Your string is #{user_input}!"
elsif
puts "There are no s's in your string!"
end
```

Any ideas on what I need to change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to be careful with built-in ruby methods that end with an exclamation point (`!`). A lot of them will return `nil` if no changes were made:

```
'test'.downcase! # => nil
'Test'.downcase! # => "test"
```

Since you are assigning the result to a variable, there's no need to use the exclamation point method, since those modify in-place, you can just use the normal `downcase` method.

```
'test'.downcase # => "test"
```

---

You also later on have an `elsif` with no condition, that should probably just be an `else`. It's actually executing the first line of the "body" of the `elsif` as the conditional:

```
if false
  puts "a"
elsif
  puts "b" # recall that `puts` returns `nil`
  puts "c"
else
  puts "d"
end
```

This results in

> b
>   d

being output

Comment: Than you. Removing the exclamation on downcase worked.